# IOS App deploy: Missing Marketing Icon

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, app-store, visual-studio-2017

I'm updating an IOS App for IPhone that is already deployed in the App Store.
I'm developing with Visual Studio 2017 from Windows, with a Mac in the same LAN network for the build.
The project is a Xamarin Forms project.
When I try to publish my project in the app store I receive an error that the **app doesn't contains the Marketing Icon in resolution 1024x1024px**.

I've tried to upgrade all: Visual Studio, Xamarin (also in the Mac) but nothing is changed.

If I select the image in the file Info.plist -> iTunes Artwork I receive an error message: "**Multiple itunesartwork files with the same dimensions detected**" (iTunesArtwork@2x.png was present in Resources directory of the project).

If I delete iTunesArtwork@2x.png in the Resources folder I receive a different error that the .**png image of the icon is not present**.

I don't know what I can do, how I can exit from this **deadlock situation**?

Update:
This is my asset catalog. (sorry if my Visual Studio is an italian version)
If I try to open it nothing happens:
[image]

And this is a screenshot of my Info.plist file opened:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a 1024x1024 icons into your asset catalogs. Asset catalog will be the file that end with `*.xcassets`

[image]
[image]

If you do not have the file in your project, you should add it in. You should be using the asset catalog file to store all your app icons and images.

[image]

============ EDITED ===============

If you already have existing asset catalog but not able to open it. You should:

1. Backup your asset catalog folder
2. Remove existing asset catalog from solutions
3. Create a new asset catalog and import back the icons

Comment: This file doesn't exists in my project

Comment: Add the file into your project. You should be using it to define your AppIcon and other images.

Comment: How I can add it? I don't know which is the structure of this file. I'm developing with Visual Studio 2017 in Xamarin Forms from Windows. This project wasn't developed by me and is an old project. Maybe that the structure is different for this reason.

Comment: You can refer to xamarin guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/app-icons/#Managing_Icons_with_Asset_Catalogs

Comment: You can leave other images unchanged but just update for AppIcon. What is the current way of defining the AppIcon in your project? Storing in Resources folder?

Comment: ok, as you can read in this guide my Asset Catalog is in the Info.plist file as mentioned in my question

Comment: No, the asset catalog is a separate file in project and not in the Info.plist. Info.plist is just to set the AppIcon to the one define inside the asset catalog.

Comment: I've also the Asset catalog -> Media icon in the project (as point 3 of the linked guide) but if I try to open Media with double click nothing happens. I tried also right click -> open... nothing.

Comment: Can you attach some screenshots on your Info.plist part and also the asset catalog in your project?

Comment: yes, I edited the question with the screenshots. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is you are not able to open the asset catalog file. I just tried on my side using Visual Studio 2015 is working. You can Right click on Images asset catalog and click "Open containing folder" and see whether there is any images define inside. You can try to open in Visual Studio for Mac too.

Comment: ok, thanks. I've two folders: AppIcons.appiconset and LaunchImage.launchimage. In the first folder I tried an handmade solution found online: copy an image and edit the Contents.json file with a new image reference but it doesn't worked.

Comment: Try remove the old asset catalog and add a new one to check whether it can open.

Comment: Removing asset catalog and create a new one works. Please edit your answer with this suggestion. Thanks!