# Transporter error IOS App Icon 1024x1024 missing

Tags: ios, xamarin, app-store-connect

I am developing an Xamarin IOS app on a windows box.  I have been developing this app for the better part of two years.  To get my app to Testflight, I right clicked on the IOS solution and selected "Show IPA on Build Server".  I then went to the MAC and added the IPA to Transporter and uploaded the app.  However now I am getting an error stating that the App Icon 1024x1024 is missing.  Yet I can plainly see the App Store Icon in the AppIcons.  Is there something I am missing for the App Icon?  Last year there was a place in the App Store to upload your App Icon.  I have been struggling with this for over a week and I have yet to find an answer online or anyone that can help.

The process I mentioned above worked perfect for almost two years.  The last time I uploaded to Testflight was June 2021.

Comment: Did you try to remove the asset catalog and create a new one and fill all the images ? Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46832906/8187800.

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT I thought I had fixed the issue, I created a sample project and had no issues.  I compared the configs and found that I had some differences.  However somehow ins the iOS IPA sections, somehow the box was unchecked so I had no issues.  If I check that box then I get the error in transporter EVERY TIME.  I guess my only option left is to create an entirely ne project and start transferring everything over.